# Trouble understanding classic recursion example of a factorial in Python 2.7

Tags: python, recursion

I understand the concept of recursion, where I get confused is in the flow control.  I've seen this presented two ways, one I get, kind of, the other I don't.  Example one:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n-1)
```

So in this example, if we run fact(3), the following occurs:

```
fact(3) = 3*fact(3-1)`
fact(2) = 2*fact(2-1)
fact(1) = 1*fact(1-1)
fact(0) = 1
```

or combined: `3*2*1*1 = 6`

Now for the following below, where I get tripped up is in how the flow control works.  I have it ingrained in my head that when a function is called, everything else is suspended until that function completes, at which time the program returns to main.  Here is what my brain thinks is happening below:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result
```

We call factorial(3):

```
factorial(3)=factorial(2)=factorial(1)=factorial(0)=1
```

The reason I think this is occuring is because `result` is assigned after the call and in my mind the code never gets there because flow control suspends main prior to `result` being assigned.  I think of this function as just running the test of `n==0` until `1` is returned and then the program exits.

Help me understand why I can't seem to conceputalize this.

Comment: They look the same to me.  You just wrote return n*fact(n-1) as three lines instead of one.

Comment: Yeah I know they are the same and return the same result, but I don't understand the execution of the second, that's the whole point of asking my question.  I don't understand how the program ever makes it to `result` since the recursion occurs before the assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an outline of the flow of the program. It might be a little confusing to look at but it could possibly help. Here, different tab levels represent different stacks and each line is a command the program executes.

```
factorial(3)
| factorial(2)
| | factorial(1)
| | | factorial(0)
| | |   RETURNS 1
| | recurse = 1
| | result = 1 * 1 [since n=1]
| | RETURNS 1 [returning result]
| recurse = 1 [catching returned result of 1]
| result = 2 * 1 [since n=2]
| RETURNS 2 [returning result]
recurse = 2 [catching returned result of 2]
result = 3 * 2 [since n=2]
RETURNS 6 [returning result]
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of the meaning of the word *reentrant* - it means that the function can be entered more than once. Calling the function blocks that particular spot in the flow, but it doesn't block that piece of code from executing *again* in the next call. When the last call in the chain returns, that unblocks the one before it, and everything gets unblocked in a chain reaction.

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat incorrect in your understanding that *everything else stops* before the function returns. That is not true if say, function A calls function B. In that situation, A will run until it calls B, at which point it will pause, B will run and, assuming it doesn't call other functions, return, and A will resume.

In the case of recursion, this means going deeper at each level (A, B, C, D...) until the if clause allows function N to complete without calling any other functions. From that point on, the parent functions will resume one by one, until you're back into "main", as you call it.

I'm on my phone, so typing an example is kinda cumbersome at best. I will make sure to write one once I get home. Perhaps if you wrote a function that printed "This is function X" (and maybe add some indentation) you would visualize it better.

Answer (score 0):

There is much less magic involved than you think. Each call to `factorial` is independent from each other, with each having its own set of parameters and local variables.

Let's look at just one level of recursion:

```
factorial(2)
```

Control will enter the function and the `else` block. Here, the inner call to `factorial` happens. So control will enter the function again, running into the `if` block and return 1. This ends the inner call.

Meanwhile, the outer call has been suspended. After the inner call returns, the result is stored in the `recurse` variable as control continues. Eventually, the outer call returns with 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result
```

So I guess you have an idea that `n` is local such that the call to `factorial(2)` inside `factorial(3)` doesn't mess with the first calls `n` so that `result = n * recurse` would be `result = 3 * 2` instead of `result = 1 * 1 * 1 * 1`.

The scoping rules of Python is that every variable defined inside of a function is local. That means that both `result` and `recurse` exists in several incarnations for each call to factorial where `n > 0`.

Another thing that people have problems getting is that every call to factorial is a totally different incarnation that the last.. Actually it's not different that calling a totally different function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial2(n-1)
```

So what happens is that the result of this completely different function results in the factorial of one less that what you need.. and resumes running the continuation of the original function by multiplying `n` with the factorial2 of `n-1` and return that result.

The code for factorial2 is very similar, but it calls factorial3 and it again calls factorial4.. That way there is no recursion only n different factorial functions that each multiply its own argument with the result fo a totally different function it has to wait for to calculate it's own value. This is of course silly because then you'll have a lot of the same functions with just different names and calling itself (recursion) is not anything different than calling a totally different function that does the same. In fact you can think of every call to the same function as if they were completely different instance that has nothing to do with the previous call since they don't share any other data than what is passed from caller to callee as arguments and what is returned back from the callee to caller as result just as if you were to use any other arithmetic function. As long as the answer is calculated from the arguments this will always be true. (every call with the same value always yields the same answer, ie. functional)

Answer (score -1):

As Duffymo said, both sections of are equivalent, the second is just separated into 3 lines instead of one. If you can understand the first, then what is there to not understand about the second?

```
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result
```

is the same as

```
    result = n * factorial(n-1)
    return result
```

is the same as

```
    return (n * factorial(n-1))
```

The function will start at the sent number (lets say 3), recursivley move down by calling the function again of (n-1)->(3,2,1,0), at 0 it returns 1. Then we are at (3,2,1), we use 1*1 = 1 and return that. We now have (3,2) and use 2*1 = 2 and return that. Now we have (3), where we use 3*2 = 6, and return that. With () [nothing left] we are done the recursion.

Comment: Sorry for a -1 but this doesn't really answer anything... maybe explain in more detail?